# What java library should I use for image cropping/ letterboxing?

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, crop, jmagick

I'm looking for a Java library to do image cropping / resizing.  I had planned to use jmagick, but it doesn't seem to have been maintained since 2009.

Is this the best library to use?  Any recommendations?!

**Edit**

One thing I want to do is to be able to pad an image to resize as well as crop it. i.e. if I have a 4x2 image, and I want to make it a square, I want to make it 4x4, with black or white padding at each side. 
Does this have a name in image manipulation?  Is it a function that comes with any libraries?

Comment: The standard java means do not provide data processing, but for instance provide turning character glyphs into paths, resizing, subimages, filters.

Comment: Check java-image-scaling-0.8.5  from [http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/) **or** CropFilter in Filter.jar from [http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/CropFilter.html](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/CropFilter.html)

Answer (score 21):

I maintain [Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator), a thumbnail generating library for Java, which provides means to resize images and do some simple image manipulations via a easy-to-use [fluent API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

One of the features that Thumbnailator provides is the [`Canvas`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506180014/http://thumbnailator.googlecode.com:80/hg/javadoc/net/coobird/thumbnailator/filters/Canvas.html) filter which can perform cropping and padding (or letterboxing) of resulting thumbnails.

**Padding an image**

For example, using the `Canvas` filter to pad an image can be achieved by the following:

```
Thumbnails.of("path/to/image.jpg")
  .size(150, 150)
  .addFilter(new Canvas(150, 150, Positions.CENTER, Color.blue))
  .toFile("path/to/padded-image.jpg");
```

The above will:

1. Take an original image and shrink it to fit within 150 x 150 via the `size` method.
2. Then, an additional filtering step specified by the `addFilter` method will add a blue padding (using `Color.blue`) to result in an final image with the dimensions 150 x 150.
3. Save the resulting thumbnail to `path/to/padded-image.jpg`.

Using the above code on a portrait picture results in the following:

[image: padded image]
<sub>(source: [coobird.net](http://coobird.net/img/so-8150276-padding.jpg))</sub>

**Cropping an image**

Cropping an image with the `Canvas` filter can be achieved by the following:

```
Thumbnails.of("path/to/image.jpg")
  .size(150, 150)
  .addFilter(new Canvas(100, 100, Positions.TOP_RIGHT, true))
  .toFile("path/to/cropped-image.jpg");
```

The above code will:

1. Take an original image and shrink it to fit within 150 x 150 via the `size` method.
2. Then, an additional filtering step will crop out a 100 x 100 region from the top-right hand corner of the resized image. (The `true` argument that is present in the `Canvas` constructor call indicates that an image should be cropped if larger than the specified dimensions.)
3. Save the resulting thumbnail to `path/to/cropped-image.jpg`.

An example of running the above code will be the following:

[image: cropped image]
<sub>(source: [coobird.net](http://coobird.net/img/so-8150276-cropping.jpg))</sub>

---

There are currently feature requests to make cropping a more integral part of the Thumbnailator API, so in the future I am planning to add a `crop` method which should reduce the need for calling the `addFilter` method under most circumstances.

Comment: I'm trying it and the addFilter with Canvas has been removed? It isn't accepted now :/

Comment: Well, I'm looking to crop the image to the center, but I can't found how to with your library (which seems VERY interesting! :))

Comment: Well I found, you added .crop(). Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("<youFile.jpg>"));
int min=0;
if(image.getWidth()>image.getHeight())
    min=image.getHeight();
else
    min=image.getWidth();

Thumbnails.of(image)
    .sourceRegion(Positions.CENTER, min, min)
    .size(250, 250)
  .toFile("<outputFile.jpg>");
```