# Java image create square avatar without crop and maintain proportion

Tags: java, image, crop

I have a system using jsf and prime faces and there is a upload image function and I need to generate thumbnails for this image, I found many ways on internet but none meet my requirements.

Actually I would like something like facebook avatar where we can resize and move the picture to fit into a blank square.

Requirements:

- Can be on image upload page using query, prime faces, etc...
- Can be on java side after image upload
- Can not crop image
- Must keep ratio
- Can add white, or transparent (better) area around the image if it is not square to make it square

I found some css or php examples but not for JAVA.

Thanks

Comment: *"Requirements:..."* - are you giving us a BRD?

Comment: Sash of course not, I am searching tools, libraries or techniques to do it. It should be also good for other users as it is not a uncommon task. Please review down vote.

Comment: Asking for libraries, tools etc is also off topic here :(

Comment: Yes ? Are you sure that I can not ask for a library ? Where is this rule ? But looks like that be rude is ok as we can see in your firs answer that was very helpful and related to this topic. Thanks guy !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic #4.

Comment: BTW, if you slightly modify the code of resource @Juraj gave you, you can make it serve your particular requirements. It is not so complicated. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[ImgScalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) can achieve these tasks and is simple to use.

Comment: Sounds very good but I still could not find the function that I need. I tried BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(imBuff, 100, 100, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS); but my thumbnail get 100X56 and I need 100x100 can white borders on the bigger side.

Comment: Thanks guy, you have my up vote. This lib do not fit all my needs but it is already helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't clearly understood, but now for what you want, library described in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150276/what-java-library-should-i-use-for-image-cropping-letterboxing?rq=1) seems to be even better for your needs.