# How can I create something in java to resize and position images based on aspect ratios?

Tags: java, image

I would like to write a program to take a displayed image, and have a transparent rectangle on top of the image at a fixed aspect ratio. I want to have this rectangle be able to be moved and resized to visually select a portion of the underlying image, and then when done, export the selected part of the image to a file.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use an [image cropping library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150276/what-java-library-should-i-use-for-image-cropping-letterboxing).

Alternatively, if you're trying to do-it-yourself:

- Create a `java.awt.Canvas`
- Draw your image on the canvas
- Create variables to track the location of the rectangle (x, y)
- Draw a rectangle on the canvas where (x, y) say
- Use `Canvas.processMouseEvent()` to track mouse clicks and mouse drags
- Update the (x, y) variables when drag is detected
- redraw the image and rectangle on the canvas when (x, y) change
- compare (x, y) and the rectangle's dimensions to determine what part on the  image is inside the rectange
- use [image library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach) to crop image

Some Java image libraries:

- [imglib2](https://github.com/imglib/imglib2)
- [Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!